# send javascript/json variable to a php sql request

Tags: javascript, php, json, datatables, server-side

i am using datatables with serverSide option, but i want to pass a javascript variable into php variable to use it later on php sql select request.
i need sending that var without refreshing the page.
Thanks

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#employee_grid').DataTable({
   "bProcessing": true,
         "serverSide": true,
   "bStateSave": true,
   "searching": true,
  "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']],
 
         "ajax":{
            url :"response2.php", //json datasource
            type: "post",  //type of method, by default would be get

   "aoColumnDefs" : [
     {
       'bSortable' : true,
       'aTargets' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
     }],
    
   "dataSrc": function (jsonData) {
     for ( var i=0, len=jsonData.data.length ; i<len ; i++ ) {
  
      jsonData.data[i][1] = '<font size="4px">'+jsonData.data[i][2]+'</font>';
    <?php
        $phpvar=jsonData.data[i][2];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM clientwhere id='$phpvar'";
        ...
        ?>
     }
     return jsonData.data;
   },
            error: function(){  // error handling code
             // $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
              //$("#employee_grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
              $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display","none");
            }
          }
    
        });   
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

1. From your current page (e.g. *index.php*), make a [jQuery `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) POST (or GET) request, passing in the JavaScript variable as a param, to another page (e.g. *processValue.php*).

**(POST) Example:**

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "processValue.php",
  data: { someVariable: someValue }
});
```

2. In *processValue.php*, save the receiving param's value into PHP's `$_SESSION` variable

**Example:**

```
$_SESSION["javascriptVariableValue"] = $_POST['someVariable'];
```

3. From this point on (i.e. upon request completing successfully), your `$_SESSION` variable will have the value accessible in *index.php* that you can process later

**NOTE:**

1. *index.php and processValue.php file names are used merely for example purposes...*
2. **Never** access $_POST directly without sanitizing etc. --- this is shown merely for example purposes and to get you going!
3. In *index.php* and *processValue.php*, make sure you do `session_start();`

Comment: i tryed this but the session variable doesn't update for every row, it always take the first value. i need that the session variable update on every row call

Comment: @user8045351 You should make the update call per row, then... and as for storing the value: you could store it as an array into your `$_SESSION`... a key value pair; key would be the row's id, for example... Then, when the lookup time comes, just fetch the value using the key, from your `$_SESSION`

Comment: `//processValue.php <?php session_start(); $_POST['someVariable']=filter_var($_POST['someVariable'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); $_SESSION["javascriptVariableValue"] = $_POST['someVariable']; ?> //index.php $.ajax({ method: "POST", url: "processValue.php", data: { someVariable: jsonData.data[i][0] } }); <?php echo $_SESSION["javascriptVariableValue"]; ?>`
is it correct @Rushikumar

Comment: @user8045351 Take a look at [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) Example: `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'someVariable')`. Also take a look at [Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: i tried your solution but session variable still saving only first value for all rows, what can be the problem @Rushikumar ??

Comment: @user8045351 in the array that you store in the session variable, your `id` (i.e. the *key*) should be unique per value you save... so make sure that is the case; next, make sure you execute the update per row --- trigger the update by giving the element a class...